# Ruby: most efficient way to randomize the position of some elements in an array

Tags: ruby

I have to solve a problem without a performance reduction.

I'm integrating in my editorial CMS a "sponsored" content system. Sponsored content are content that, for some days, gain a random position in my homepage.

I have my content Class, and some contents have a flag "sponsored".

In my HomeController I call the contents for my Cover.

```
@content = Content.for_cover
```

The result is an array of 20 objects, and some of these objects are sponsored.

Content are ordered by they default scope (publication_date DESC) so in my homepage they are ordered from the most recent to the oldest, but I need that sponsored content "override" the default scope and take a random position.

I'm trying to find the best solution: I don't want to reduce the performance of my homepage rendering with a lot of query.

Any idea?

**More info**

I added a scope method that filter for sponsored so my query return all my contents (20) ordered by publishing date and with the sponsored in the front.

```
 @content = Content.for_cover
```

return me something like:

```
c = [s,s,s,s,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16]
```

where s are "sponsored".

I must take every single "s" and move it in a random position.

```
c = [c1,c2,c3,s,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,s,c9,c10,s,c11,c12,c13,c14,s,c15,c16]
```

Comment: Do the randomised content items replace existing items, or just come in between so as to push them down?

Comment: What about my answer? Before it was "under construction" :P

Answer (score 3):

```
array = [ "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "c9", "c10", "c11", "c12", "c13", "c14", "c15", "c16" ]
array.sort_by.with_index { |el, i| el =~ /s/ ? rand(array.size) : i }
#=> ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "s3", "c8", "c9", "c10", "s4", "s2", "c11", "c12", "c13", "s1", "c14", "c15", "c16"]
```

Of course in the real app you'd check for `el.sponsored?` or something instead of `el =~ /s/`.

Comment: I don't need to randomize the array, only the sponsored element.

Comment: So the `c`s in your example HAVE TO stay in order?

Comment: Also can two `s`s be next to each other? Because if they can't the positioning is not really random.

Comment: @RobertoPezzali So does this answer your question or do you need anything else?

Comment: I'm trying different solutions here... :)

Answer (score 1):

edit in response to comment:

Try this:

```
sponsered = @content.delete(&:sponsered)

sponsered.each do |s|
  size = @content.size
  @content.insert(rand(size), s)
end
```

---

Why not use [shuffle](http://www.omniref.com/ruby/2.1.1/classes/Array##shuffle)?

```
@content = Content.for_cover
@content.shuffle
```

example:

```
array = %w[s s s c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c]
 => ["s", "s", "s", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"]
array.shuffle
 => ["c", "s", "c", "c", "s", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "s", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"]
```

Comment: I need to randomize only the order of "s" elements. Others element must keep the ordering by date!!!

Comment: what attributes do the 's' elements have?

Comment: the same attribute of the "c" elements, except for a flag "sponsored"

Answer (score 0):

```
c = [ "s", "s", "s", "s", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "c9",
  "c10", "c11", "c12", "c13", "c14", "c15", "c16" ]
hsh = c.group_by { |e| e[0] }
s = hsh.delete 's'
rest = hsh.map( &:last ).reduce :+
result = ( s + Array.new( rest.size ) ).shuffle.map do |e| e || rest.shift end
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this (`Content` class just for model emulating):

```
class Content
  attr_reader :sponsored

  def initialize(sponsored)
    @sponsored = sponsored
  end

  def inspect
    sponsored.to_s
  end
end

a = Array.new(4) { Content.new(true) } + Array.new(6) { Content.new(false) }
p a
#=> [true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false]

a.select(&:sponsored).each { |v| a.insert rand(a.size), a.delete(v) }
p a
#=> [true, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, true]
```

If the sponsored elements are always before the others you can use `take_while` instead of `select`.